# Grails WAR can't find file in java class

Tags: java, grails, war, libav

In my project i need to use **libav** to convert videos and audios. So i need to include libav tools in my project. 
This is my project structure :

```
grails-project  
 |  
 |-- .classpath  
 |-- .groovy  
 |-- .project  
 |-- .settings  
 |-- application.properties  
 |-- grails-app  
 |-- lib  
 |   |-- avconv -->>> `This is the folder which contains libav tools`
 |-- scripts  
 |-- src
 |   |-- groovy
 |   |-- java
 |   |   |-- Converter.class -->>> `This is my converter class`
 |-- target  
 |-- test  
 |-- web-app
```

Also i use java interface for libav which is [avconv4java](https://github.com/vbauer/avconv4java).
It runs a process to execute libav commands and I set libav path like this:

```
AVCommand command = new AVCommand();
command.setToolPath("lib/avconv/bin/avconv.exe");
```

Inside the java interface it passes the path as argument to **ProcessBuilder** and it starts it etc.

**In development environment it runs very well**. However when I deploy war and try to convert a video I got the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "lib/avconv/bin/avconv.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I looked my deployed structure and found out that avconv folder is not in the lib folder. So i added these lines to **BuildConfig**:

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir, args ->
   copy(todir: "${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/avconv") {
       fileset(dir: "lib/avconv", includes:"**")
   }
}
```

Now avconv is in lib folder -like development environment- However, I still get the same error. What should I do to make it work?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

GRAILS VERSION: 2.4.5
Developing in intelliJ
Deployed to Tomcat 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative paths will be expected to start from the root of the tomcat folder. Assuming the file in question is on your classpath, you can call `getResource` to access it and pass the absolute path to `AVCommand`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I solved it by giving absolute paths, so i will accept this as answer for future comings :) I wish you had answered earlier :)))